# How can i remove the item from the list and screen when onTap is used?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to remove the item from the list and the screen when the "onTap" is used. At the moment it removes the item from the list but I cannot remove it from the screen. How can I achieve that?

[image]

here is my code:

```
          SliverList(
             delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
             (context, i) => ListTile(
                title: Slidable(
                  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                  child: new Text(
                    items[i],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Remove',
                      color: Colors.red,
                      icon: Icons.delete,
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          items.removeAt(i);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          childCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this happens because `setState` does not trigger your Sliver widgets to perform rebuild.

Try wrapping your `SliverList` in [`StatefulBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html).

e.g.

```dart
StatefulBuilder(builder: (innerContext, innerSetState) =>
  SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (context, i) => ListTile(
        title: Slidable(
          actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
          actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
          child: new Text(
            items[i],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
          secondaryActions: <Widget>[
            IconSlideAction(
              caption: 'Remove',
              color: Colors.red,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              onTap: () {
                innerSetState(() {
                  items.removeAt(i);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      childCount: items.length,
    ),
  ),
)
```

The most important part here is `innerSetState` function which is passed in the builder's function argument. It rebuilds the entire `StatefulBuilder` subtree.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: However, it doesnt work if i create another list, Sliverlist. For example, I have list(SliverList) that contains numbers 1-4 as the above image shows. And, another list(SliverList) for different types of list, let's say A-Z. I have used your solutions for both lists.But, it works only on ONE list

Comment: do you use separate `StatefulBuilder` for each list?

Comment: I have used separate StatefulBuilder for each list

Comment: `StatefulBuilder` rebuild depends on the use of `innerSetState` method - where do you use in the code (it should be called inside of the builder), and are you sure that you use `innerSetState` and not the regular `setState` from the parent class?

Comment: If I start deleting from the first list, it only allows me to delete from the first list Not the second list. Or, vice versa

Comment: when copying the code to apply it for another list - do you change your variables as well? In this code it's `items` variable and it has to be changed to the new one with the new list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194585/discussion-between-dan-and-george).